# Iterating over two lists concurrently within a function in R

Tags: r, function, loops, tidyverse

I would like to iterate through two lists using a function to redefine variables. I am using R (tidyverse functions mutate, case_when, map). I have time-series panel data that is broken down by state.

I want to assign values by state with the values that correspond with every 108th row of the data.

Here's the lists I am trying to run through:

```
states_small <- 
     dat$farmland[seq(1, length(dat$farmland), 108)]
     #vector with size [1:22] every 108th value

hn_departments <- c("HN-AT", 
                    "HN-CH", 
                    "HN-CL", 
                    "HN-CM", 
                    "HN-CP", 
                    "HN-CR", 
                    "HN-EP", 
                    "HN-FM",
                    "HN-GD",
                    "HN-IN",
                    "HN-IB",
                    "HN-LP",
                    "HN-LE",
                    "HN-OC",
                    "HN-OL",
                    "HN-VA",
                    "HN-YO")
```

Here's the very inefficient code that works (I have to do this for 15 different variables):

```
dat2 <-
  dat %>% 
  mutate(farmland = case_when(HASC_1 == "HN-AT" ~ dat$farmland[1], 
                                HASC_1 == "HN-CH" ~ dat$farmland[109],
                                HASC_1 == "HN-CL" ~ dat$farmland[217],
                                HASC_1 == "HN-CM" ~ dat$farmland[325], 
                                HASC_1 == "HN-CP" ~ dat$farmland[433], 
                                HASC_1 == "HN-CR" ~ dat$farmland[541], 
                                HASC_1 == "HN-EP" ~ dat$farmland[649], 
                                HASC_1 == "HN-FM" ~ dat$farmland[757],
                                HASC_1 == "HN-GD" ~ dat$farmland[865],
                                HASC_1 == "HN-IN" ~ dat$farmland[973],
                                HASC_1 == "HN-IB" ~ dat$farmland[1081],
                                HASC_1 == "HN-LP" ~ dat$farmland[1189],
                                HASC_1 == "HN-LE" ~ dat$farmland[1297],
                                HASC_1 == "HN-OC" ~ dat$farmland[1405],
                                HASC_1 == "HN-OL" ~ dat$farmland[1513],
                                HASC_1 == "HN-VA" ~ dat$farmland[1621],
                                HASC_1 == "HN-YO" ~ dat$farmland[1729]))
```

Finally, here's the code I've been trying using map2. I cannot seem to get the map2 function to work, although if I'm being honest--the map function confuses me.

I basically want to be able to run a list of states through the first half of the case when argument above and have it equal the values from the seq list small_states.

```
#FIRST TRY
dat2 <-
  dat %>% 
  map2(hn_departments, states_small, mutate(farmland = case_when(HASC_1 == .x ~ .y)))
#error: Error: Mapped vectors must have consistent lengths: * `.x` has length 18 * `.y` has length 22

#SECOND TRY
dat2 <-
  dat %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(farmland = map2(hn_departments, states_small, 
                                    case_when(HASC_1 == .x ~ .y)))
#error: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `farmland`. x object '.x' not found ℹ Input `farmland` is `map2(...)`.
```

Any advice on how to go about fixing this, or streamlining the working code for efficiency?

Comment: The second try is close. In `map2`, the third argument should be a function or a formula. In your case it is neither. You can turn it into a formula by writing `~ case_when(...)`, but that might go wrong since the `case_when` also uses a `~` internally. To turn it into a function, you can write `function(x, y) case_when(HASC_1 == x ~ y)`

Answer (score 1):

We could create a named vector where value is the new value that you want to change to and name is the current value in the data.

We can then use `across` to apply this for multiple columns. Assuming all the columns that you want to change start with `'HASC'`, you can do :

```
library(dplyr)
name_vec <- setNames(states_small, hn_departments)
dat <- dat %>% mutate(across(starts_with('HASC'), ~name_vec[.x]))
```